# How to find object in Array or dictionary using anything

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate

I've got new work, and its on objective-c at this moments, I can't used struct and etc.
Please can somebody help me, I need to find value in NSArray (or I can change it to NSDictionary if this is easily).
[I've got NSArray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5YJF.png) with 4 similar dictionaries. I've got key for Subcategories->ID. `NSString *titleKey =  paramsCell[@"category"];`

I need to find in all of this dictionaries this ID and catch 'Locale' which confirm for this id.

```
        NSString *predicate2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"_subcategories.id == \"%@\"",titleKey];
        NSArray *tempArray = [_categoryDictionary filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: predicate2]];
```

What I tried:

^^^^ It doesnt work

I've tried to change Predicate to

```
'NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:titleKey];'
```

I fully don't understand these %@ @% %""@"%"@%"@, I want to cry.....

Please, can somebody explain how I can resolve it.
In swift it looks like like .map{$0.subcategories} I suppose

**Added:**

[for @Larme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mK7K.png)

I need to find in _categoryDic (which can be Array or Dict, I can change it) Subcategories->id which equal to my titleKey. And catch subcategory->Locale which in 1 dict with id.

My situation:
We got cells,  so when we receive it from server they didn't have name. We receive only Category ID for cells. We should to compare it category with our dictionary and place Title on the cell (which in our categoryDic-> locale)

Comment: `paramsCell[@"category"]`: That's a `NSArray`, not a `NSString` according to your screenshot. In the end, you want what exactly? The value for `locale` key is a `NSString`?

Comment: @Larme, sorry for bot detailing description. this is method cellForRowAtIndexPath, so titleKey can be only NSString. I've tried to find in _categoryDictionary value in 'Locale' and send it to the label, in _CategoryDictionary I've got all categories. My cell got only ID for category. I need to compare my cell category id (title key with categoryDic->Subcategories->ID and show on my label categoryDic->subCategories->Locale

Comment: Sorry, I mean `_categoryDictionary[@"subcategories"]` is a `NSArray`, so you can't do `subcategories.id` on it. Are you saying it's also a NSArray of NSDictionaries? Could you just print `_category_Dictionary`? And also tell us what you want in the end? If you could create you final output yourself: `NSArray *output = ...`, or `NSDictionary *output = ...` or `NSString *output = ...`?

Comment: @Larme, I've tried with Array and Dictionary. I can change it in any format if you need it.

Comment: It doesn't matter, we just need to know what you data really look like.

Comment: @Larme. I've place some additional information in body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thans for @Larme and @Rob Napier for help!

```
NSString *targetId = @"toFind";
    NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (NSDictionary *element in _categoryDictionary) {
        NSArray *subcategories = element[@"subcategories"];
        for (NSDictionary *aSubcategory in subcategories) {
            if ([aSubcategory[@"id"] isEqualToString:targetId]) {
                [results addObject:aSubcategory[@"locale"]];
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is rarely a need for NSPredicate when just working on an NSArray. The power of NSPredicate is primarily for Core Data (which can convert them into SQL calls on the database rather than linearly searching), or is some cases where you have a very complicated or highly dynamic query that is more easily expressed as a predicate.

If you would have written this in Swift as a simple map/filter on an Array, the best approach in ObjC is a for-in loop.

```
NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSDictionary *element in _categoryDictionary) {
   if ( ... check your condition ... ) {
      id value = ... convert element to what you want ...
      [results addObject: value];
   }
}
```

(Your question is very confusing about exactly what you're trying to filter for and what conversion you want, so I'm just providing the standard loop structure. You can fill in your specifics.)

If you really need a predicate, I can rewrite this in that form, but you need to be much more exact about what your input data is and what output you expect. You'd want to give that as an explicit example, not a screenshot, with "this is the input array in ObjC syntax, and this is the output array in ObjC syntax." (But I don't think you need a predicate for this.)

Comment: Thank you Rob. I'm trying like this:             NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray new];
            for (NSDictionary *element in _categoryDictionary) {
               if (element[@"subcategories.id"] == titleKey) {
                   id value = element[@"subcategories"][@"locale"][@"title"];
                   cell.textLabel.text == value;
               }
            }

Comment: ok… I'm not sure what you are hoping that does.  You're not adding the result to the `results` array, and you're checking if `text == value` over and over again. (You should see a warning that you're not using the result of the `==`. Don't ignore warnings.)

Comment: when I use element[@"subcategories.id"]] - it return nil, if I used element[@"subcategories"][@"id"]]; - it drop app. how I should write it correct?) it almost final!!!))))

Comment: It's https://pastebin.com/7JW7ieu6 and you don't seems to care about wha's the hierarchy of your object. That's why I asked you for more details. `element[@"subcategories.id"]]` returns nil? That's normal. Why value do you expect it would return? Side note, if you want only one value don't use `results` as a `NSArray`, but as a `NSString` directly. And naming `_categoryDictionary`, I would expect it to be a `NSDictionary`, but it's in fact a `NSArray`, misleading!

Comment: @ Larme, Thank you a lot ! You both resolve my problem! I've spent 5 hours on this problem. I've googled for __NSSingleObjectArrayI and others. Omg I should go to drink something!

Comment: `__NSSingleObjectArrayI` is a hidden subclass for Apple. It means it's a array for one single object and it's not mutable (ie, immutable). In "visible" classes, it's just a `NSArray`.